# How to iterate over pandas dataframe items in a fast way?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am newbee in Python and need an advice how to iterate over dataframe items in a faster way?
My implementation:

```
weights = histCaps.copy()
for index, row in histCaps.iterrows():
    for column, item in row.iteritems():
        weights[column].loc[index] = item/row.sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont loop, better is use vectorized [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) for better performance:

```
histCaps = pd.DataFrame({
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                 })

weights = histCaps.div(histCaps.sum(axis=1),axis=0)

print (weights)

          B         C         D         E
0  0.235294  0.411765  0.058824  0.294118
1  0.263158  0.421053  0.157895  0.157895
2  0.166667  0.375000  0.208333  0.250000
3  0.200000  0.160000  0.280000  0.360000
4  0.500000  0.200000  0.100000  0.200000
5  0.363636  0.272727  0.000000  0.363636
```

**Detail**:

```
print (histCaps.sum(axis=1))

0    17
1    19
2    24
3    25
4    10
5    11
dtype: int64
```